# Filter / Delete incorrect rows (plus above and below)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have got a large dataset.
I want to delete all incorrect rows. Additionally i want to delete some rows before and after the incorrect row.

I found something helpful. But unfortunately it does not work out for me.
I think i has to do with the "rownames" but i am not able to fix it.
So i appreciate any helpful advices.

```
library(dplyr)

var1 <- 1:20
var2 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
var3 <- rep(3, 20)

dat <- data.frame (var1, var2, var3)
View(dat)


extract.with.context <- function(x, rows, after = 0, before = 0) {

  match.idx  <- which(rownames(x) %in% rows)
  span       <- seq(from = -before, to = after)
  extend.idx <- c(outer(match.idx, span, `+`))
  extend.idx <- Filter(function(i) i > 0 & i <= nrow(x), extend.idx)
  extend.idx <- sort(unique(extend.idx))

  return(x[extend.idx, , drop = FALSE])
}

extract.with.context(dat, dat$var2==0, after = 1, before = 1)

View(dat)

#expected output
var1 <- c(1,2,3,9,14,15,16,20)
var2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
var3 <- rep(3,length(var2))
dat <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
View(dat)
```

Comment: What's "Incorrect rows"? Also please add expected output

Comment: Incorrect rows are those var2==0

Comment: If the before / after is the same, you can also use `dat[!zoo::rollsum(dat$var2 == 0, k = 3, fill = FALSE) > 0,]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get the index of rows where `column` is equal to `value` and remove the rows for indexes `indx`, `indx + after` and `indx - before`.

```
extract.with.context <- function(df, column, value, before, after) {
    indx <- which(df[[column]] == value)
    df[-c(indx, indx + after, indx - before), ]
}

extract.with.context(dat, "var2", 0, 1, 1)

#   var1 var2 var3
#1     1    1    3
#2     2    1    3
#3     3    1    3
#9     9    1    3
#14   14    1    3
#15   15    1    3
#16   16    1    3
#20   20    1    3
```

Comment: Whenever subsetting rows/element by position, I'd recommend you check if any values actually were found - otherwise you might get errors or unexpected results. Check for example `x <- 1:10; i <- which(x>10); x[-i]`. That's why I usually prefer logical indices but because of the after/before that's more difficult here.

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, quite possible. We can put an additional `if` condition to check `indx` has found any value or not.

Answer (score 0):

got some profesional help :)

```
toDelete<- c(which(dat$var2==0) , which(dat$var2==0)+1, which(dat$var2==0)-1)
dat <- dat[-toDelete,]
```

or even better (controlling for cases where nothing is deleted)

```
toDelete<- c(which(dat$var2==0) , which(dat$var2==0)+1, which(dat$var2==0)-1)
if (!identical(toDelete,numeric(0))) { dat <- dat[-toDelete,] }
```

Comment: Did you notice that you run `which(dat$var2==0)` three times in a line? Perhaps that's because people on SO always try to do everything in one line but from my point of view that's very redundant and therefore unclean/inefficient coding. Run it once, store the result in an object and then call that whenever you need it